# Foreach Loop - Unable to retrieve updated variable value

Tags: php, loops, codeigniter, foreach

I have a simple foreach loop inside a do while loop that reads a variable from database :

```
do {
   foreach ($a as $b => $c) {
       echo $this->var->var_status;
       if ($this->var->var_status == 1) {
                                    
          $StopLooping = true;
          break;
       }
    }
} while ($this->project->var_status == 0);
```

For my purpose, breaking either the foreach loop or the do while loop would accomplish what I need but for some reason it seems that once I update the variable var_status in database the loop is unable to   fetch the changed variable and keeps assuming the initial value of var_status(0) .

I am new to php and I am not sure if this is expected behavior , it seems like the variable gets stored in memory and after the loop has started running updating it in database will not update the variable inside the loop .

I tried using unset after reading a few threads but it doesn't seem to work .

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to provide more context. How do you run this script, how/when do you retrieve the data from the database... are you making this database update *during* the loop?

Comment: That's because `$this` is called an instance.. it holds the values locally and so if you update the value in the database, your local instance doesn't have the new value.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio I probably should have mentioned it but the instance is declared in the code and if I add an echo statement with $this->var->var_status right after the do while loop starts it gets the correct value from the database .

Comment: We still need more context from you. It is unclear when/where you instantiate this class or when/where you make the db operation.